# Why can't I access internet via my router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet

I have a Linksys E3000 router that I'm trying to set up. I've connected the cable from my ISP to the `Internet` port of the router, and accessed its GUI via the wireless connection (had no other cable). I've edited the Internet setup section to use `Static IP` and provided the Internet IP address, subnet mask, default gateway, and DNS options as given to me from my ISP.

I expected the internet to be tethered then. From the diagnostic console in the router's web UI I was able to ping outside addresses (namely, `8.8.8.8`) successfully. From the laptop I can ping the router's address, but not any outside address, and tracerouting to any outside address goes no further from the router's LAN address, so I guess the problem has something to do with the router forwarding.

The routing table of the router is as follows:

```
Destinatio LAN IP   Subnet Mask      Gateway          Hop Count   Interface

(WAN Port network)  (my WAN subnet)  0.0.0.0          1           Internet (WAN)
192.168.20.0        255.255.255.0    0.0.0.0          1           LAN & Wireless
0.0.0.0             0.0.0.0          (My ISP Gateway) 1           Internet (WAN)
```

It seems fine to me, but I still can't access the Internet.

Is there anything that I am not seeing? Is there anything else I have to set up? Has the problem anything to do with not setting it up with the software included in the CD? (because I'm using Linux and the software came for Windows and Mac!) And if not, what is wrong or how can I troubleshoot this problem?

**EDIT**: The IP address assigned to my WAN port of the router is also unreachable from the LAN...

Comment: Can you ping the outside interface of the router?  Can you ping 41.78.109.73?  41.78.109.73 is not assigned to your router's outside interface right?  Also, just curious but most residential internet setups use a dhcp outside interface.  Were you assigned a static IP?

Comment: @JasonH No I cannot ping that address.. And yes it is assigned to the router outside address. And yes I was assigned a static IP. It's a long story, lazy ISP, bad customer relations, and more politics...

Comment: @JasonH Oops! Sorry that address is the gateway address given to me by the ISP.. My IP is also unreachable from the LAN...

Comment: What happens if you configure your PC with the static IP and other info given to you from your ISP, without using the router? Does that work without problems (ie. is this router specific)?

Comment: @bigbadonk420 I just tried that, it works fine without the router. It is router specific...

Comment: This is a dirty solution, but if you're only using one computer you could always set the router to "bridge mode" and then set up the static IP on your computer. Otherwise, this is a router configuration issue. I would read the manual. This could also be caused by the WiFi being cut off from the cable network, sometimes a default setting in the router. Might be worth checking out.

Comment: @bigbadonk420 unfortunately other PCs and mobile phones will access this network :( and I'm in the process of reading the manual. Still nothing related to the issue that I can make use of!

Comment: This might be obvious but have you tried factory resetting the device and then running the install CD to help you configure the router? See http://support.linksys.com/en-eu/support/routers/E3000

Comment: @bigbadonk420 I did reset to the factory settings, but I am unable to use the CD application cuz there is no Linux version of it. I may have to get a Windows PC or MAC to try that out...

Comment: It shouldn't matter, I don't think it does anything you can't do from the router interface. Can you specify in your question exactly what steps you took when you configured it? Remember that I/we cannot see the router interface to try to explain extensively (Images are great)

Comment: So you can ping the LAN IP of the Linksys router, but you can't ping the Linksys router's WAN IP?  You either need to reset the router back to system defualt which it looks like you did, or upgrade the firmware.  Is this router new or did you get it used?  What you're saying you did should be working just fine.  It's definitely a router issue.

Comment: I did reset couple of times. I'll try to document my steps in more details and use the Linksys software. More details to come...

Answer (score -2):

Routing table is OK.

You must configure NAT to translate local IP addresses to WAN IP address.

Comment: Care to expand on how the OP might go about doing that?